# Regex return string from 10th position till first occurrence of hyphen

Tags: regex

I have a string like so ""10680756-1000-RET" and I am trying to write a Regex to return the string from the 10th position till the first occurrence of hyphen

Exmaple: return this "1000" from the above.

I tried this with no luck -

> ^.{9}([0-9]{?=-})

Comment: Split with `-` and get the second element. Why use regex?

Comment: OP regex fails because there is no quantifier after `[0-9]`. There must be a `+` or `*` and the lookahead is just redudant as `[0-9]` cannot match a hyphen. @Ratan, is it written in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^.{9}(.*?)(?=-)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQ3cK7/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Is this OK:

```
^.{9}([^-]*)
```

The string you're looking for is in group 1.